# Programatically created ASP.NET TextBox retains Text value after PostBack even if Control is cleared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls, textbox, postback

I have a drop down menu, and based on which item is selected, I call a web service and then dynamically create some text boxes.

The first time I drop down the menu and select an item, it works perfectly, and the text boxes are created and populated dynamically. However, the next time I drop down the menu (after the first postback), and select something different... after the second postback, the original values remain in the textboxes.

I am clearing all of the text boxes out of the placeholder, then re-creating them, and then setting a NEW value, how can they retain the OLD values... especially if I controls.clear them from the page?

Note: The second time they are being created, the textbox IDs DO end up being the same. Could that have something to do with it? This duplicate ID functionality will need to be supported.

My code, called from Page_Load, is as follows: (edited to add more code)

```
Private Sub RefreshEntity()

        Dim XmlRecords As New XmlDocument
        Dim XmlRecordsNode As XmlNode
        Dim EntityType As String = EntityTypes.SelectedValue
        Dim Entity As String = RecordValue.Value
        Dim FieldName As String
        Dim FieldValue As String

        FieldPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear()

        If RecordList.SelectedValue <> "Select..." Then
            Try
                XmlRecordsNode = LoginInfo.SharePointConnectWebService.GetMetaData(LoginInfo.WSUser, LoginInfo.WSPass, _
                                                                                  EntityType, Entity)
                XmlRecords.LoadXml(XmlRecordsNode.OuterXml)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ConfirmLabel.Text = "<b>Error:</b><br>" & ex.Message.ToString
                Return
            End Try
        Else
            SetProperties.Visible = False
            Return
        End If

        For Each OneNode As XmlNode In XmlRecords.SelectNodes("Fields").Item(0).ChildNodes

            FieldName = OneNode.Name
            FieldValue = OneNode.InnerText

            Dim newLabel As Label = New Label()
            newLabel.Text = FieldName & ":   "

            Dim newTextBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
            newTextBox.ID = "Field-" & FieldName
            newTextBox.Text = FieldValue

            Dim newLine As Label = New Label()
            newLine.Text = "<br><br>"

            FieldPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newLabel)
            FieldPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newTextBox)
            FieldPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newLine)

        Next

        SetProperties.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

And the RecordValue.Value is a hidden field that gets populated in every Page_Load:

```
                RecordValue.Value = RecordList.SelectedValue
```

Where RecordList is my DropDown menu.

Comment: Do you have the same behavior occurring if you move this code to the Page_Init event?

Comment: I don't see where this is dependent on the selected item in the drop-down list, so I don't see why this would be any different based on the selected item... What am I missing?

Comment: @TheGeek If I put this in Page_Init, the controls NEVER show up

Comment: @David I added code showing how the returned XML is dependent upon what is in the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to ViewState or the Posted values clobbering your values.

Once a control is dynamically added to the controls collection it needs to catch up with all the page life cycle events that have already fired.  In the case of a post back this means that the ViewState and/or the posted form value will clobber the .text property on the TextBox based on the order you're adding the dynamic controls to the controls collection and setting the .text property.

To fix this you can disable ViewState by setting the [`.EnableViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property to false on the dynamically generate controls also add the controls to the controls collection before you set any properties on them.

```
For Each OneNode As XmlNode In XmlRecords.SelectNodes("Fields").Item(0).ChildNodes

    FieldName = OneNode.Name
    FieldValue = OneNode.InnerText

    Dim newLabel As Label = New Label()
    Dim newTextBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
    Dim newLine As Label = New Label()

    newTextBox.ID = "Field-" & FieldName

    newLabel.EnableViewState = False
    newTextBox.EnableViewState = False
    newLine.EnableViewState = False

    FieldPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newLabel)
    FieldPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newTextBox)
    FieldPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newLine)

    newLabel.Text = FieldName & ":   "
    newTextBox.Text = FieldValue
    newLine.Text = "<br><br>"

Next
```

Comment: Aaron, I had tried setting the EnableViewState to false previously, however I hadn't tried switching up the ordering. Unfortunately, the code above produces the same result. Is it OK that the TextBoxes are getting the same ID? There has to be something I'm missing...

Comment: It's almost as though the pre-postback TextBox is getting re-added to FieldPlaceHolder and the .Text update isn't sticking...

Comment: I also tried disabling the viewstate of the FieldPlaceHolder too... no luck.

Comment: try calling this function from prerender instead of onload.

Answer (score -1):

You're not storing the value in a Session variable and then putting it back into the text box later in your code?

Comment: No, I am not storing the value in a session variable.

Comment: I store the drop down's value in a hidden field instead, since the dropdown also gets dynamically populated when the page loads, based on something else.